# How to Hide Item Count in Outlook 2010 with VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

This code fails:

```
Sub Clear_ItemCount()
    Dim oAccount As MAPIFolder
    Set oAccount = Application.Session.Folders("myaccount@gmail.com")

    Dim oInbox  As MAPIFolder
    Set oInbox = oAccount.Folders("Inbox")
    oInbox.ShowItemCount = olNoItemCount

    Set oInbox = Nothing
    Set oAccount = Nothing
End Sub
```

Item count is still visible:
[image]

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863885(v=office.14).aspx), it seems that it should work. It says it does not work with "Public" folders, but, based on [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-share-a-public-folder-A2835011-D524-4A5C-A207-05C159BB2A97), i think "Public" folders are shared folders on an Exchange server (not using an Exchange server).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: is that the count or `UnRead Items`?

Comment: @0m3r Want to hide both. That why i used `olNoItemCount`.